# Creating two tables in database on activation hook

Tags: plugin-development

I have been trying to generate two tables in database on activation hook. But it generates only the first one table on activation hook . What am i doing wrong in my code?

```
class Datetimepicker_Tables{

function __construct(){
    add_action('init',array($this,'create_tables'));

}

function activate(){
    $this->create_tables();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function create_tables(){
        global $wpdb;

        $date_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_dates';
        $time_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_timeslots';
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $date_table = "CREATE TABLE $date_table_name (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
             `month` int(11) NOT NULL,
             `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) $charset_collate;";

        $time_table = "CREATE TABLE $time_table_name (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `bid` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
            KEY `bid` (`bid`),
            CONSTRAINT `booking_timeslots_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bid`) REFERENCES `booking_dates` (`id`)
            )  $charset_collate;";  

            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
            dbDelta( $date_table );
            dbDelta( $time_table );
}
}

$tablesclass = new Datetimepicker_Tables();
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array($tablesclass,'activate'));
```

Comment: *REFERENCES `booking_dates`* should be `REFERENCES $date_table_name`.

Comment: Are you talking about this -> "$date_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_dates';"  ?

Comment: Yes, the table name.

Comment: I don't think so, i made a variable and passing a name of the table in that variable.

Comment: I was saying that you didn't use the proper table name in the `CONSTRAINT` clause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the proper table name in your `CONSTRAINT` clause:

```
CONSTRAINT `booking_timeslots_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bid`) REFERENCES `booking_dates` (`id`)
```

That should be:

```
CONSTRAINT `booking_timeslots_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bid`) REFERENCES `$date_table_name` (`id`)
```

where `$date_table_name` (as I could see) is the correct table name.

Comment: To add to Sally's answer - the reference in the SQL for the table is "booking_dates" which lacks the database prefix defined in the variable $date_table_name, so the table "booking_dates" doesn't actually exist when the query is run.

Comment: You're welcome Afzal. And thank you @butlerblog. :)